# Unclear output origin

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, javascript-objects

I understand why the first output is 10, but I am unable to understand why the second output is 2

```js
var length = 10;
function fn() {
 console.log(this.length);
}

var obj = {
  length: 5,
  method: function(fn) {
    fn();
    arguments[0]();
  }
};

obj.method(fn, 1);
```

Comment: You should debug the code. You can set break points and inspect the values and step into method calls. That should help you understand how it works and why you get the output you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) in general is an object inside every function that contains the values of the arguments passed to each specific function. In your case:

```
obj.method(fn, 1);
//          ^  ^  arguments object will have those 2 values
```

So when you `arguments[0]()` you actually call `fn` again **but** in this case you trigger `fn` from an object (the `arguments` object) **and that's the key point**.

Because of this, `this` keyword in your `fn` is a reference to the `arguments` object, which in this case has the length value of 2 like the arguments you passed to your `obj.method(fn, 1)` call and the value that is being logged the second time.

Chapter **1 & 2** of [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes) book has a more extended explantation of how `this` behaves and might help you understand a bit more about your case.

Also, it is worth noting that an object has no `.length` property, but while the `arguments` object is an `array-like` object (check link about `arguments` object), **it does**.

Comment: can you explain again, I didn't understand.

Comment: You call `fn` with `arguments` as receiver, therefore `this` equals `arguments`. I suggest taking a look at the [MDN `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) documentation.

Comment: If you're looking for the output `5` you have multiple options. The simplest being setting `fn` as property of `obj` and calling it with `obj` as receiver. `obj.method2 = fn` then `obj.method2()`. Alternatively you can use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass a specific this argument: `fn.call(this)` inside `method`. Both would log `5`.

Comment: @AbhayKumar I have extended my answer. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @MichalisGarganourakis Yes, Thanks a lot.